# Is it possible to get matching and non-matching records with one query in sqlite? If so, how?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm creating a "quiz" app. I need to generate 4 answers based on the question, with 1 correct answer and 3 incorrect answers. I know you can do this with two queries, with the first query returning a row that will return a correct answer the question, then another query that returns random answers from the same table. But, I was wondering if it is possible to do this with just one query.

Comment: Could you add the two queries you're using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 2 queries on an `UNION`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE D = 1
UNION
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE D = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

A boolean expression returns 0 or 1; just order by that:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY C = 1 DESC
```